# Center two divs to middle inside main div

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

I want to center two divs (facebook website name and facebook like/share button) to middle of div. I create one main div:

```
.fb_div{
 background-color:black;
 width:250px;
 height:150px;
 position:absolute;
 left:20px;
 top:20px;
}
```

and two divs into .fb_div

```
.facebook
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
    color:#3b5998;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.fb_share
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

`margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` does not help me to center it to middle. Here is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/de10uqtf/1/)

EDIT: I can not set left position to specific value because width of like and share button depends on text ( If i join from USA=like or SLOVAK=páči sa mi to )

Answer (score 1):

If your going to use absolute positioning, you might as well do this:

```
.facebook{margin-left: 70px; }
.fb-share{margin-left: 74px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9vpcok1/

Comment: this works, but the only downside is that if he re-sizes the box, he'll have tweak the margins every time, thought this would be pretty easy with something like Sass

Comment: but i want same space on left and right side. I can not set left position to specific value because width of like and share button depends on text/ country , USA=like SLOVAK=páči sa mi to

Answer (score 0):

Both .facebook and .fb_share need a width.

```
width:80px; /*or such*/
```

Though I would also remove the display:inline-block form the .facebook class.

http://jsfiddle.net/de10uqtf/10/

Comment: but i want same space on left and right side. I can not set left position to specific value because width of like and share button depends on text/  country , USA=like SLOVAK=páči sa mi to

Comment: in that case you can use text-align:center; on .fb_div if you keep .facebok as an inline block, but the problem becomes the iframe, you have to control it's with, I don't think it's possible to control iframe width using only CSS, you may have to use javascript, and since they don't reside on the same domain that may be another challenge to overcome, at this point it may be easier to hack it with what Rahul and Joey described, just make it wide enough to accommodate both languages..>?

Answer (score 0):

Please Find the updated code.

```
.facebook {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:#3b5998;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    left:30%;
}
.fb_share {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: absolute;
    left:30%;
    top:20%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de10uqtf/9/)